# How can I check to see how many tables exist in a sqlite file (Objective-C)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, uitableview, persistence

What I want to do is let the user save lists of data in sqlite tables.  When the user loads a tableview, I want there to be a cell corresponding to each of the sqlite tables that currently exist.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLite includes a magic table called sqlite_master which lists all the tables and indexes in the database. You can query this for entries matching the correct type that don't start with SQLite's bookkeeping prefix.

Use this SQLite query:

```
SELECT
    Count(*)
FROM
    sqlite_master
WHERE
    type = 'table'
    AND (NOT Name LIKE 'sqlite_%');
```

Or, if you want the names of each table:

```
SELECT
    Name
FROM
    sqlite_master
WHERE
    type = 'table'
    AND (NOT Name LIKE 'sqlite_%');
```